# about the poles of the sum of the reciprocals of the zeta function

Tags: calculus

I am interested in finding out where the poles of the function are located
$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{z^j}{\zeta (j+2)}$$
, and I have been calculating some points and I would like to conjecture that it has poles for values ​​of z in each prime number, I also use another similar series
$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{z^j \zeta (j+2)}{\zeta (j+2)^2+1}$$

and you can see poles in values ​​for z = 1 ,2,4 and but I have not been able to find more because I think they are poles in the square roots of some prime numbers but no all ,
I think it will possible to proof using Euler product formula
thanks to the help of reuns, the results in principle are contradictory it seems at first as reuns says that the function in question has poles in each positive integer, but the numerical calculations initially indicated other results, but when you represent the numerical results are confirmed how strange is all this
[image]

Comment: reuns says it has a simple pole at each *square free* positive integer and not at each integer. Note that $\mu(n)$ is zero if $n$ is not square free and for those $n$'s the term $\mu(n)/(n(n-z))$ disappears, i.e., there is no pole at a non square free integer.

Comment: sorry thanks for the comments I just realized @reuns was right, the initial assumption was not totally true, but here the important thing is that the numerical method used works at least for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{z^j}{\zeta (j+2)} = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\mu(n)/n^2}{1-z/n}$$

--> simple pole at each square free positive integer, of residue $-\mu(n)/n$.